Spark with Hive Table or View not found in new Session
I have created spark table using df.write.saveAsTable('df')
Now when I query it using spark.sql It works fine.
I can see the data present in spark-warehouse.
But when I create new Spark session, I get into errors
AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `df` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS.; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [df], [], false

I have enabled hive support on spark session as
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

I am using jovyan pyspark jupyter notebook docker image
My docker-compose.yml looks like this
version: "3.3"

services:
  pyspark:
    container_name: spark_connector
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/jovyan/work


this because your SparkSession havent connected any hive metastore, add "hive.metastore.uris" in your sparkConf can solve this,like this:
new SparkConf().set("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://127.0.0.1:9083")

